# NoClassDefFoundError when trying to use default YAML file for play! framework application

Tags: java, playframework, playframework-2.0, classloader

I am trying to develop an app which uses ebean to create a database and then displays the tables in web pages using play framework 2.2.0
These are my model classes and I am also using in memory database.

Parents.java:

```
    @Entity
    @Table(name="parents")
    public class Parents extends Model {

    @GeneratedValue
    public Long id;

    @Id 
    @Constraints.Required
    public String name;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy="parent", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    public List<Children> childs = new ArrayList<Children>();
    }
```

And this is the Children.java:

```
    @Entity
    @Table(name="children")
    public class Children extends Model {

    @GeneratedValue
    public Long id;

    @Id
    @Constraints.Required
    public String name;

    @ManyToOne
    public Parents parent;
    }
```

I have set Global.java to load the default .yml file. The file looks like this:

```
parents:
    - !!models.Parents
        id: 1
        name: MOM
        childs:
            - !!models.Children
                 name: SON

children:
    - !!models.Children
        id:              1
        name:            SON
        parent:          !!models.Parents
                              name: "MOM"
```

And, this is my Global.java file:

```
public class Global extends GlobalSettings {
@Override
public void onStart(Application app) {
    // Check if the database is empty
    if (Ebean.find(Parents.class).findRowCount() == 0) {
        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    Map<String,List<Object>> all =  Map<String,List<Object>>)Yaml.load("default.yml");

    Ebean.save(all.get("parents"));
    Ebean.save(all.get("children"));
    }
}
```

}

The evolution script runs without errors and the application worked fine at first. But after a few runs, I got this error (I don't exactly remember what I changed in my models):

```
Unexpected exception
NoClassDefFoundError: Models/Children (wrong name: models/Children)
```

I am not really familiar with YAML format. So I thought that must be it and surprisingly I even succeeded resolving the error by changing my yaml file format on a trial and error basis. But after I exited the framework console and ran it again, I got the error again and this time I couldn't resolve it anymore and I suspect it may have deeper roots. I tried using clean and recompile at the play console with no success. I even tried restarting my computer (following the infamous IT-crowd advice: Have you tried turning it off and on again?!) to no avail. BTW, I am new both to java programming and Stack Overflow so there could be even huge and gross mistakes in what I've posted. Thanks is advance for your help and time.

Comment: Full stacktrace would have made it clear... Now you can do some self help by referring to this - http://javareferencegv.blogspot.com/2013/10/debugging-javalangnoclassdeffounderror.html

Comment: I have solved the problem by only defining the elements of relationship on the owning side (many side). Instead of adding childs field in parents, and parent field in children table in YAML file, I only inserted parent in children table.
But I still wonder why should I get an error when inserting both sides of a relationship consistently, and why a classloader error?